# How to download Firefox via command line FTP

Tags: command-line, firefox, ftp

I am attempting to install Firefox on my Mac, which currently does not have a browser. From a bash terminal I have `ftp` installed and am currently connected to the internet. However, I have been unsuccessful in connecting to their FTP server.  How do I go about installing Firefox for my Mac via the command line?

Comment: Can your client use `http` protocol? See this [Mozilla support issue](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1078139).

Comment: The Safari browser is a default part of the OS X, did you delete it and if so, curious as to why?

Comment: I was installing it for a friend.  Their OS X had safari installed but on the launcher it showed a cancel sign over it, and when attempting to launch it an error would occur in regards to the version of OS X.  I thought it may be necessary to update the computer's operating system to the newest version in order to get safari to work, so in the mean time I just installed firefox to give basic browsing functionality via firefox

Comment: You may be able to launch Safari anyway by starting the binary from a shell. Inside the app there is contents/MacOS/Safari which when started from a shell (e.g. bash) often bypasses restrictions launchservices might impose (such as rules from info.plist). If the app is broken that won't work of course.

Comment: I'll give it a try next time I have the computer in front of me, I'm familiar with launching binaries in linux so I imagine it is very similar. However, it is likely the app could be broken.

Answer (score 15):

You can skip the download step, and mount it directly over the internet like so:

```
hdiutil attach https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/43.0.4/mac/en-US/Firefox\ 43.0.4.dmg
```

Saves a step, time, and storage space!

Comment: That's pretty neat! :) +1

Comment: It's one of those hidden gems that Apple sneaks in. I tried attaching directly over the internet like that many years back to see if it would work, and it actually did. Definitely a neat trick. ;) Of course, I realized afterwards that it's mentioned in the man page. Heh.

Comment: You're mounting it over HTTP, which is pretty insecure. Does the command support HTTPS ?

Comment: Fair point. Fixed! Yes, it does support HTTPS.

Answer (score 8):

ftp access to ftp.mozilla.org was turned off (see [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1078139), thanks Davïd). However, you can use `curl` from the command line:

```
curl 'https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/43.0.4/mac/en-US/Firefox%2043.0.4.dmg' >~/Desktop/'Firefox 43.0.4.dmg'
```

That gets the latest (as of this writing) US English release for Mac OS X of Firefox.

You can get a directory listing thusly:

```
curl 'https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/43.0.4/mac/'
```

That outputs HTML, but it's pretty simple HTML, so it shouldn't be a problem reading it to get a different language. You can also chop additional elements off the path, for example if you want a different version:

```
curl 'https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/'
```